# PHP & JAVASCRIPT - How to take values from multiple input fields after clicking on the buttons which are connected to each input field?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a subpage for changing the username, password, mail etc.
I have 4 inputs and 4 buttons next to each input in my php file. 
I am wondering, how can I take the value from one of the input field after clicking on the button next to it? I want to take that values without reloading the page.
What's more first click on the button changes the input field from "disabled" (in PHP) to "prop('disabled', false)" (in JAVASCRIPT).
Then, you can enter something into the input field.
The second click on the same button changes similarly (from "abled" to "disabled"). So I want to take the input value after SECOND CLICK on the button.

HELP ME! :<

My code:
[HTML] https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE9K9.png
[JAVASCRIPT] https://i.stack.imgur.com/syoKa.png

Comment: Please post actual code in question, not images of code. First we can't review this without opening numerous links and if anyone needs to copy some code to modify it we can't from an image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something through jQuery:

```
$('.edit_profile').on('click', function(){
   // if still disabled, return;
   if ($(this).prev().is(':disabled')) return;
   // otherwise we go for value:
   var value = $(this).prev().val();
   console.log(value);
});
```

And please take a look for function: `prev()` https://api.jquery.com/prev/

For passing your fields to php use `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "myphpscriptforupdate.php",
    dataType: 'html',
    data: { 
        p_year: $('#p_year').val() 
    },
    success: function(data){
        // data = response from php (the things you echoed)
        }
});
```

Comment: Wow, it is working! Thanks!
Now... how to extract for example only birth year?

Comment: User jquery selector: `$('#p_year')` if i got you right?

Comment: Oh, yes. Right. Thank you so much! 
You are the best!

Comment: Oh, just one more question! How to pass this variable from jQuery to PHP? 
I need to update e.g. birth year in my database so I need to store typed value in PHP.

Comment: I did update answer above.